# How to delete an item from my dataset which is already removed from the GUI in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

When I hit the trash-can-icon button the selected OneLineListItem gets removed from the GUI. Unfortunately, it isnt removed from my datatable so it will appear again when I restart the application. But I have no clue how to connect the methods on_start / remove_item with my datatable. Do you have any ideas how I can solve the problem?

its only the important part of the code

```
class MainApp(MDApp):

def build(self):
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"

def on_start(self):
    df = pd.read_csv("date.csv", index_col=False)
    for i in df.index:
        self.root.ids.md_list.add_widget(
            SwipeToDelete(text=df["Name"][i])

        )

def remove_item(self, instance):
    df = pd.read_csv("date.csv")
    self.root.ids.md_list.remove_widget(instance)
```

and my stuff from kivy (only the important part)

```
<SwipeToDelete>:
size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
height: content.height
type_swipe: "hand"
anchor:"left"

MDCardSwipeLayerBox:
    padding: "8dp"

    MDIconButton:
        icon:"trash-can"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
        on_release:
            app.remove_item(root)

MDCardSwipeFrontBox:

    TwoLineIconListItem:
        id: content
        text: root.text
        secondary_text: app.get_date_item()
        _no_ripple_effect: True
        IconLeftWidget:
            icon:"account"
```